# SQLAlachemy filter with '&' operator and Provide SQL query for the filter

Tags: python, postgresql, join, sqlalchemy

I have three tables and their classes are given below,

```
class Values(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'values'
                    
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, ForeignKey('identities.id'), primary_key=True)
    attribute = db.Column(db.Integer, ForeignKey('attributes.id'), primary_key=True)
    value = db.Column(JSONB)

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"<Values {self.id}>"


class Identities(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'identities'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    uuid = db.Column(db.Text)

    user_data = db.relationship(Values, backref='identities')

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"<Identities {self.id}>"


class Attributes(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'attributes'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    schema = db.Column(db.Integer, ForeignKey('schemas.id'))
    name = db.Column(db.Text)
    syntax = db.Column(JSON)

    user_attribute = db.relationship(Values, backref='attributes', primaryjoin=id == Values.attribute)

    def __init__(self, name, syntax, id, schema):
        self.name = name
        self.syntax = syntax
        self.id = id
        self.schema = schema

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"<Attributes {self.name}>"
```

Lets say, sample data in those table are as follows: -

**values**

1, 1, "kiran"

1, 2, "kumar"

**identities**

1, a

**attributes**

1, 1, "userName", 'a'

2, 1, "displayName", 'b'

As you can see The relation from identities to values table is **one to many** and both entries in values table belong to single identity in identities table.

I have a filter like,  "*Get all identities whose userName is 'kiran' and displayName is 'kumar'*".

I have written an sqlalchemy query for that, which is not correct.

```
db.session.query(Identities).join(Values, Identities.id == Values.id).filter(((Attributes.name=='userName') & (cast(Values.value, db.String())=='"kiran"')) & ((Attributes.name=='displayName') & (cast(Values.value, db.String())=='"kumar"'))).all()
```

The above query as expected does not return any result.
But when i make it an **or** operation it return results.

The reason being there is no context of 'identity' table in the query and doing an **and** on `1, 1, "kiran"` this row for both userName and displayName obviously does not return any result.

How do you construct proper query for this issue?

**Or**

Can you provide basic SQL query for the above tables and condition?

**Can we use self join to achieve this using aliased function?**